# Running Windows Steam on Linux (Using Wine)

Tags: windows, wine, steam

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time and am trying to figure a way to play Windows games on Linux. I've read you need to use Wine, and I'm just wondering how exactly I go about doing this correctly. I've read a lot of conflicting information.

Answer (score 39):

**NOTE:**  This installation may or may not work anymore with Steam and PlayOnLinux.
There isn't any guarantee that this will work, but you are free to try.  If you are going to downvote this answer, please feel free to make suggestions instead or add any recent findings.

---

I would recommend `PlayOnLinux` as a front end for Wine.

To install `PlayOnLinux` run the following commands from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

*Note, PlayOnLinux installs Wine if it is not installed.*

After it is installed and you run it for the first time, you will see an application that looks like this:

[image]

Click on the Install button.  In the search box, type in Steam.  Select Steam.  Then click Install in the lower right.  *PlayOnLinux should download the needed files to install Steam.  Note: Unfortunately, not every application is downloaded like this.  Some applications will have to be downloaded manually, or you need the installation media.*

[image]

*PlayOnLinux should configure Wine for the application if it is found in the install menu like Steam is.  Sometimes you might need to search https://www.winehq.com for tweaks to games to make them work correctly.*

When it is completed, all you should have to do is to click on Steam in the box, then click Run above, or you can double-click on Steam to launch it.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ideas on how to get this to work with the Steam Link?

Comment: @ForkrulAssail Unfortunately, I don't have a Steam Link, so I wouldn't have the first idea on how to test it.  I wish I could be more help on that one.  Maybe you can ask a new question on configuring it, or asking it on one of the other like the gaming site:  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 8):

Once you have installed wine, you can download the Windows version of steam and install it.  Then you run this version of steam through wine and download your windows games.  I have had mixed success with this approach, but in many cases it's better than dual booting.

Comment: Revisiting this in 2020, it seems that running steam under Linux and running windows games under Proton works much, much better.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the Linux version of Steam and enable proton/playonlinux in the game's properties. Steam will then enable the install button. As part of the install, it will download the nessasry files for proton.
You can also do this with Linux compatible games if you wish.
The advantage of doing it this way is that it allows you to play Linux only games still, as well as playing Windows/Linux games natively.

Edit. You may need to enable steam play in the steam settings first.